# Writing all zeros in latch

Tags: digital-logic, flipflop, microprocessor, logic-gates, processor

I am trying to implement a instruction pipeline but getting one issue. Please help me :

How can we write all zeros in a latch using hardware?

I am not that much into Electrical Engineering so please go easy on me :)

Comment: Ground the inputs to the latch. Of if you need to optionally latch zeros, then preceded the latch with a mux and ground one of the mux inputs, selecting that one when you want it. (Some latches may include a clear input, as well, synchronous and asynchronous.)

Comment: @jonk, your comment should be posted as an answer.

Comment: @ThePhoton  It is so obvious it just seems the OP must really be asking some other question. But what the heck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just ground (0V is usually take as a zero) each of the latch input bits.

I suppose you really mean that you'd like to optionally latch zeros, though. (It is hard to imagine you'd just want to only latch zeros.) In that case, just preceded the latch with a mux and ground one of the mux inputs, selecting that one when you want it. Or, some latches may include a clear input, as well, either synchronous and asynchronous. So that may be another option, as well.

I've already written probably twice what you did in writing your question. You really should get in the practice of writing more, so that people writing answers can write less.

Comment: Thanks your feedback Jonk. I will try to improve move in future.